# How to track disk sector read/write in details in Linux?

Tags: linux, disk

I am learning Linux disk IO, and I met a disk corruption.
A disk sector is being written with garbage data.
I want to track the write to that disk sector, i am not sure if there is a way in Linux.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: That's true, in fact there's a question in Unix & Linux Stack Exchange wich could help to wangt13:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/55212/how-can-i-monitor-disk-io

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should take a look at `sysstat`: https://github.com/sysstat/sysstat

Its a package for monitoring disk I/O

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development.